# Binding the Width of columns to DependencyProperty with a IValueConverter

Tags: wpf, binding, width, ivalueconverter

I am trying to make the width of a column in a Grid element variable. For this I have a DependencyProperty "ItemWidth" and bind the Width-element from the Button to this DP. Because of the TwoWay-Binding, I need a converter that converts doubles to DataGridLength.

My MainWindow.xaml looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:utils="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <utils:ColumnWidthConverter x:Key="columnWidthConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="{Binding Path=ItemWidth, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource columnWidthConverter}}" Click="Shorter_Click">shorter</Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="{Binding Path=ItemWidth, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource columnWidthConverter}}" Click="Longer_Click">longer</Button>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The ColumnWidthConverter.cs is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class ColumnWidthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;
            else
            {
                DataGridLengthConverter cv = new DataGridLengthConverter();
                object result = cv.ConvertFrom(value);
                return result;
            }

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;
            else
            {
                DataGridLengthConverter cv = new DataGridLengthConverter();
                return cv.ConvertTo(value, typeof(double));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the MainWindow.xaml.cs looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public double ItemWidth
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ItemWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemWidthProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemWidth", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));

        private void Shorter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ItemWidth -= 100;
        }

        private void Longer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ItemWidth += 100;
        }
    }
}
```

So the Width of the Buttons should change when I click one of the Buttons. But this does not happen. Can you tell me why that is and some sort of solution?

Comment: Hi, did you intentionally wrote this code in your convert function? return new DataGridLength(100); are you supposed to use this one? return result;

Comment: Sorry, that was for debugging purposes. Its not working with return result either.

Comment: The ItemWidth changes but not the size of the Buttons.

Comment: What do you mean size? is it for height or width?

Comment: Both. But the important thing: the width does not change..the visualization stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set no source in the binding, hence it is relative to the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx), which you do not appear to have set anywhere, if you add it that should work. e.g.

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ...
```

You might want to (i.e. you *definitely should*) look into [debugging data bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) if you are not familiar with it.

You also bind properties which have no need for the converter, in fact the converter will probably cause problems here, did you not mean to bind the `ColumnDefinition.Width`?

Comment: Thank you very much for that information! Unfortunately the setting of DataContext did not fix the problem.

Comment: @Hauke: Then give us some binding errors if there are any. Also, why are you binding the Button.Width? See the nate i added...

Comment: This is only an example application. Actually I need to manually implement a GridSplitter. For this I need to change the width. There are no binding errors. That is what I dont understand. In my understanding the code should work fine.

In the project at the company the structure of the grid is very complicated so that I have to use the width property of the button (alternatively Border) element. And because of that I need the Converter..

And there arent any other errors.

Comment: @Hauke: Currently you are binding a `double` to a `double`, you do not need a converter for that. Did you set a breakpoint in the converter, is it even called?

Comment: Yes, it is called. And when I try to solve it without using a converter, it says: "Cannot create default converter to perform 'two-way' conversions between types 'System.Double' and 'Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridLength'." But actually I only need the method Convert (not ConvertBack). The resulting object is a DataGridLength, so that there are no errors left.

Comment: @Hauke: That can not be the case for the above example where you do not bind the column width! What are you doing?

Comment: Unfortunately you are right. In the above example I would not need a converter. It works fine without. In the actual application though its not working and I get the mentioned error. But there I bind the width property of a Border to the ItemWidth. So no apparent difference for me. I need to sort that out now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

i use the following for my GridSplitter

```
public class DoubleToGridLengthConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        double i = (double)value;

        GridLength result = new GridLength(i);

        return result;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        GridLength g = (GridLength)value;

        return (double)g.Value;

    }

}
```

xaml

```
Width="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=GridSplitter, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource GridLengthConverter}}"
```